# Spring boot stomp server gives warning for resolved org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, stomp, sockjs

I have been working with spring boot and stomp server for sometime now. After using it for sometime I found that my logs are filled with the following waring messages.

```
08:58:36.026 [38] [http-nio-8080-exec-8] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class java.util.LinkedHashMap] with preset Content-Type 'application/javascript;charset=UTF-8'],
```

To investigate further what is happening I set spring framework logging to `TRACE` and the rest of the log is given below.

```
08:58:35.991 [94] [clientOutboundChannel-14] TRACE org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.XhrStreamingTransportHandler$XhrStreamingSockJsSession - 1 message(s) to flush in session d3zz_wqj,
08:58:35.991 [94] [clientOutboundChannel-14] TRACE org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.XhrStreamingTransportHandler$XhrStreamingSockJsSession - Session is active, ready to flush.,
08:58:35.991 [94] [clientOutboundChannel-14] TRACE org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.XhrStreamingTransportHandler$XhrStreamingSockJsSession - Preparing to write SockJsFrame content='a[\"\\n\"]',
08:58:35.991 [94] [clientOutboundChannel-14] TRACE org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.XhrStreamingTransportHandler$XhrStreamingSockJsSession - Writing to HTTP response: a[\"\\n\"],
08:58:35.992 [94] [clientOutboundChannel-14] TRACE org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.DisconnectedClient - Looks like the client has gone away,
08:58:35.994 [94] [clientOutboundChannel-14] DEBUG org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.XhrStreamingTransportHandler$XhrStreamingSockJsSession - Closing SockJS session d3zz_wqj with CloseStatus[code=1011, reason=null],
08:58:35.994 [94] [clientOutboundChannel-14] DEBUG org.springframework.web.socket.handler.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator - XhrStreamingSockJsSession[id=d3zz_wqj] closed with CloseStatus[code=1011, reason=null],
08:58:35.994 [94] [clientOutboundChannel-14] DEBUG org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler - Clearing session d3zz_wqj,
08:58:35.994 [94] [clientOutboundChannel-14] TRACE org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'getTracer',
08:58:35.994 [102] [clientInboundChannel-21] TRACE org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'getTracer',
08:58:35.994 [94] [clientOutboundChannel-14] TRACE org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'getTracer',
08:58:35.994 [100] [clientInboundChannel-19] TRACE org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'getTracer',
08:58:35.994 [94] [clientOutboundChannel-14] TRACE org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'getTracer',
08:58:35.994 [103] [clientInboundChannel-22] TRACE org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'getTracer',
08:58:35.994 [103] [clientInboundChannel-22] DEBUG org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler - Forwarding DISCONNECT session=d3zz_wqj,
08:58:35.994 [103] [clientInboundChannel-22] TRACE org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompEncoder - Encoding STOMP DISCONNECT, headers=null,
08:58:35.996 [46] [tcp-client-loop-nio-4] DEBUG org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler - Cleaning up connection state for session d3zz_wqj,
08:58:35.996 [46] [tcp-client-loop-nio-4] DEBUG org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler - Closing TCP connection in session d3zz_wqj,
08:58:35.998 [94] [clientOutboundChannel-14] DEBUG org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.StompSubProtocolHandler - Failed to send WebSocket message to client in session d3zz_wqj,
08:58:36.005 [38] [http-nio-8080-exec-8] TRACE org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedRequestContextFilter - Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@2f4e2263",
08:58:36.005 [38] [http-nio-8080-exec-8] TRACE org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - \"INCLUDE\" dispatch for POST \"/socket/error\", parameters={}, headers={masked} in DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet',
08:58:36.010 [38] [http-nio-8080-exec-8] TRACE org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - 2 matching mappings: [{ [/error]}, { [/error], produces [text/html]}],
08:58:36.010 [38] [http-nio-8080-exec-8] TRACE org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'basicErrorController',
08:58:36.010 [38] [http-nio-8080-exec-8] TRACE org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest),
08:58:36.018 [38] [http-nio-8080-exec-8] TRACE org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod - Arguments: [org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@2f4e2263],
08:58:36.021 [38] [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor - Found 'Content-Type:application/javascript;charset=UTF-8' in response,
08:58:36.022 [38] [http-nio-8080-exec-8] TRACE org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod - Error handling return value=[<200 OK OK,{timestamp=Fri May 27 08:58:36 UTC 2022, status=200, error=OK, path=/socket/ws/067/d3zz_wqj/xhr_streaming},[]>], type=org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest),
08:58:36.026 [38] [http-nio-8080-exec-8] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class java.util.LinkedHashMap] with preset Content-Type 'application/javascript;charset=UTF-8'],
08:58:36.026 [38] [http-nio-8080-exec-8] TRACE org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - No view rendering, null ModelAndView returned.,
08:58:36.027 [38] [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Exiting from \"INCLUDE\" dispatch, status 200, headers={masked},
08:58:36.027 [38] [http-nio-8080-exec-8] TRACE org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedRequestContextFilter - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@2f4e2263,
```

Looking at the logs I can see that before the server could send the frame `a["\n"]` to the client, the client has already disconnected and trying to send the frame to closed socket is causing the error. Is there any proper way to handle this error?

Answer (score 0):

The server seems to want to write a `LinkedHashMap` as `application/javascript;charset=UTF-8` and cannot find a converter to do so. Which makes sense.

I guess the return type (probably mime-type here but could be java type) is wrong. We would need a look at your endpoint to give a better answer on how to fix this.

Comment: which endpoint? The websocket registration endpoint or data recieving endpoint?

Comment: The endpoint sending data

Comment: There is no specific endpoint to send data, I just subscribe to queues in message broker to send data to client.